# How can I redirect html codes to controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

This is my code

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Auth;

class SideNavDeliGroceryComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $navigations = [
            'dashboard' => [
                'title' => 'Dashboard',
                'url' => 'deligrocery.dashboard.view',
                'icon' => 'delirush-am-dashboard',
                'permission_for' => 'dashboard'
            ],
            'customers' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Customers',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.customer.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-customers',
                    'permission_for' => 'customer'
                ], [
                    'title' => 'Orders',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.customer.order-management.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-orders',
                    'permission_for' => 'order'
                ]
            ],
            'delivery' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Rushers',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.delivery.rusher.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-rushers',
                    'permission_for' => 'rusher'
                ], [
                    'title' => 'Job Order Management',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.delivery.job-order.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-delivery',
                    'permission_for' => 'job-order'
                ]
            ],
            'grocery_partner' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Partner Management',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.grocery-partner.partner-manager.view',
                    'icon' => 'fa-solid fa-store',
                    // 'icon' => 'delirush-am-food-partners',
                    'permission_for' => 'rusher'
                    
                ]
            ],
            'service_settings' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Delivery Service Configuration',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.delivery_service_settings.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-delivery-fee',
                    'permission_for' => 'delivery-service-configuration'
                ]
            ],
            'finance' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Finance Management',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.finance.merchant-partner-commission-report.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-finance',
                    'permission_for' => 'finance'
                ]
            ],
            'Tools' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Category Type Management',
                    'url' => 'deligrocery.tools.category-type.view',
                    'icon' => 'delirush-am-finance',
                    'permission_for' => 'finance'
                ]
            ],
        ];
        
        // $navs = ['customers' => [],'delivery' => []];
        // $permissions = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->getAllPermissions()->groupBy('permission_for');
        // foreach ($permissions as $permissionKey => $permission) {
        //     foreach($navigations as $navKey => $navigation) {
        //         $permissionFors = array_column($navigation, 'permission_for');
        //         $check = array_search($permissionKey, $permissionFors);
        //         if($check !== false) {
        //             array_push($navs[$navKey], $navigation[$check]);
        //         }
        //     }
        // }
        
        $view->with([
            'navs' => $navigations,
            'current' => request()->route()->getName()
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want to put this code `<i class="fa-solid fa-store"></i>` inside array in 'icon' label

Comment: I want to put this html code inside the array icon <i class="fa-solid fa-store"></i>

Comment: You can simply write html there if you want, if you have encoding problem while rendering then bypass html encode of blade file.

Answer (score 2):

You can put that html code in the array and then when you render it in the blade file you will need to escape it so it displays as html, you can do so like this:

```
{!! $icon !!}
```